# ActiveRecord Include, how to use in nested records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I currently have the following:

```
@threads = current_user.threads.includes(:user, :thread_members)
```

I then take threads and do the following:

```
@threads.each do |thread|

  thread_members = thread.thread_members_active(current_user)

      @threadList << {
        :id => thread.id,
        :uuid => thread.uuid,
        :user_id => thread.user.id,
        :last_activity_at => thread.last_activity_at,
        :user_count => thread_members.length,
        :user_photos => thread_members.collect { |thread_member|
          {
            :id => thread_member.user.id,
            :photo => thread_member.user.photo(:thumb),
            :name => thread_member.user.full_name
          }
        },
        :caption => thread.caption
      }

end
```

The issue here is that every EACH loop, rails is hitting the DB for the same basic records. Rails sees to be caching as I see CACHE in the log but it's mighty messy. Leaves me wishing I could do some type of includes so there wasn't so many db requests.

Any ideas on how this can be optimized? Something around including all the users in one db hit?

Thanks

Comment: What's the code for thread_members_active?

Comment: @Cypher it's a method that does the following: return self.thread_members.joins(:user).where("users.guest = false OR users.guest = true AND users.fname IS NOT NULL OR users.id = #{current_user.id}")

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any DB queries in the loop, you have to define everything that's used there in the named associations that are included, so instead of a `thread_members_active` method you'd define a `thread_members_active` association which has the same behavior. Note that the association also needs to use `includes` on `user`. Can't give you more right now, but maybe that helps a bit.

Edit: Check out the "Eager loading of associations" part of this doc:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html